# Avoiding redeclaration errors without include guards

Tags: c, include, dependencies, redeclaration

If I want to avoid redeclaration errors without using include guards, is the basic rule that the dependency tree must be that: one or more trees only.

Any time a parent can be reached two different ways, then a violation occurs?

for example:

declarations.h includes string.h
data.h includes declarations.h
data.c include data.h
ui.c includes data.h and string.h

This generates a redeclaration error because both ui.c and includes string.h two different ways: directly and via data.h. Thus, the structure is not a tree, since ui.c has multiple paths to the same parent.

Is there a way to have a multiple paths to the same parent and not get a redeclaration error?

Comment: I don't get it. Could you state your assumptions and your real question more clearly, please?

Comment: It is likely *a lot* easier to come up with unique include guards than unique dependency trees. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: make life easy on your self, ALWAYS use 'include guards' on every header file that you write.  It is easy, use <filename>_h for the include guard.  look at any system header file for: `#ifndef <filename>_h  #define <filename>_h`  and at the end of the file: `#endif`   Those three lines are all that is needed to be added to the header file to have a 'include guard'

Comment: I don't want to use guards. I want to have a clean dependency network that does not rely on guards. I need to understand the viable shapes of the network to achieve this.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve what you want is "put everything in one single file" - That is a very clear dependency. And this also shows how undesirable it is what you want to achieve. You *want* to use guards - You just don't know it, yet.

Comment: @tofro I am done using guards. I don't appreciate people making incorrect assumptions about my motives. The question is about how to structure dependencies to avoid redeclaration. If you don't want to answer it, fine, don't answer it, but please don't lecture me about your programming philosophy.

Comment: Yes, it is (or rather, should be) possible to find a dependency tree in a collection of source files and arrange everything to get rid of guards. The problem is: Any change to the source will re-arrange that dependency tree and you will be ending up with largely un-maintainable code. It is not clear to me why you apparently cannot live with a practice that is and has been considered a "best practice" in C programming over decades now (so it's not "my" programming philosophy. But everyones but yours, apparently).

Answer (score 0):

After studying this problem for some time, it seems that the necessary graph shape is not a tree. Basically the dependencies will be clean as long as the graph has no cycles and follows a single cardinal rule which is that there can only be a single path to any given parent. So, for example:

[image]

So, in this network we see that parents are shared, and also children can be shared, but there is nowhere that there are multiple routes to any given parent from the same child. One mathematical term for the shape is a *disjoint network*. In a disjoint network, any two paths can share only an endpoint, but no other vertex/edge.

Comment: I'd suggest you start your quest for purity with your compiler and system include files. Make sure you cover includes that define criss-cross dependencies (i.e. modules that tend to call *each other*), next level of fun will be *callbacks* and their related data structures